# gnuplot bash script variables

Tags: linux, bash, gnuplot

I have been creating a quick bash script that will generate some resource numbers and display them via gnuplot. I ran into an issue the second I changed the filenames in the gnuplot command to reflect a variable my script sets up for file location. Example code is below. 
Any idea why I am having this issue? I am guessing that gnuplot is not expanding my variable I setup, I just cannot figure out what I need to change. Thank you.

```
testFile=/var/log/testing.log
testFileTwo=/var/log/testingTwo.log
gnuplot -persist -e 'set xlabel "TIME"; set ylabel "PERCENT" ; set yrange [0:100]' -e 'plot ${testFile} smooth bezier, ${testFileTwo} smooth bezier'
```

As soon as I run this script, I receive the following error.

```
plot ${testFile} smooth bezeri, ${testFileTwo} smooth bezier
      ^
line 0: invalid complex constant
```

Comment: It seems that your variables are not being substituted correctly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bash does not expand variables inside `'` single quotes. If you use `"` double quotes after the second `-e`, bash will expand `${testFile}` and `${testFileTwo}` before passing the resulting string to gnuplot.

EDIT: use `-e "plot '${testFile}' ..."`, to make sure that plot receives the name inside quotes.

Comment: I have no idea how I missed that. Thank you! Ran into another issue right away from gnuplot saying "/" is an invalid expression. But that is another issue I will start looking down. Thank you again for the quick response.

Comment: I will accept your answer in 5 minutes once I am allowed to.

Comment: My bad. You should use single quotes again around the filename within that. I'll update my answer.